# Does django offer usage of postgres' json type?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Since [django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/) is out and there is new `django.contrib.postgres` package, can we use postgres' [json type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html) natively in models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django 1.8, `django.contrib.postgres` has an `HStoreField`, but does not have a `JSONField`.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/4427) about this, so `django.contrib.postgres` will hopefully have a `JSONField` in Django 1.9.